# О неполном значении приставки ПРИ в глаголе "пригорюниться",

Tags: словообразование, семантика, приставка

Принято считать, что приставка ***ПРИ*** обозначает **неполное** действие. **[По Розенталю](http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=34#pp34)**  значение совершения действия **не в полном** объеме или на ограниченный срок: приоткрыть, приостановиться.

Но как это понять? Возможные **варианты:**

1. **Степень** признака:  не очень-то  горевал.
2. Пригорюнился, но на **короткое** время (без причины).
3. Пригорюнился по **конкретному поводу** (коня украли, птица пропала).

Какие **приставки** могут заменить приставку ПРИ?  Может ли на выбор глагола с приставкой ***ПРИ*** влиять стилистика текста?

**ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ**

Тексты  на тему: глагол ***пригорюниться*** и  сходные по значению глаголы ***припечалиться*** (устар.), ***запечалиться, опечалиться.***

1. А. К. Толстой. **Князь Серебряный (1861-1863)**

Но царь любил Адрагана и ***припечалился***, что пропала его лучшая птица.

2. Русская народная сказка  **«Иван-царевич и серый волк»**

*Много ли, мало ли времени прошло, пробудился Иван-царевич, видит — коня нет. Пошел его искать, ходил, ходил и нашел своего коня — одни кости обглоданные. **Запечалился** Иван-царевич: куда без коня идти в такую даль? Ну что же, — думает, — взялся — делать нечего. И пошел пеший. Шел, шел, устал до смерточки. Сел на мягкую траву и **пригорюнился**, сидит.*

3. Наринэ Абгарян. **Всё о Манюне (сборник) (2012)**

Авось мама не заметит. — Дядя Миша умоляюще посмотрел на нас: — Вы только не говорите ей, ладно? — Заметит, это же литровые банки, они у нее все наперечет, — обнадежили мы его. — Мать их за ногу, — **пригорюнился дядя Миша**. — Пойдем пирожки есть, а то Ба спустится за нами и увидит, что вы тут натворили, — потянула я его за руку.

4. Евгений Водолазкин. **Лавр (2012)**

Дверь открылась. На пороге стоял его знакомый. Он отступил назад, как бы освобождая Арсению пространство. Арсений же ***опечалился***, потому что понял, что в действительности этому человеку требуется разбег. Открывший с криком разбежался и двумя руками столкнул Арсения с крыльца. Когда Арсений пришел в себя, снова светила луна. Он взял пригоршню снега и потер застывшее лицо.

5. Дмитрий Глуховский. **Метро 2033 (2005)**

*И вышли из его чрева первые создания его, имени которых сейчас не помнят. И были они большие и сильные, напоминая самого Великого червя. И полюбил их Великий червь. Но нечего им было пить, ибо в мире не было воды, и издохли они от жажды. И тогда Великий червь ***опечалился***. До тех пор неведома ему была **печаль,** ибо некого было любить ему, и одиночество было неизвестно. Но создав новую жизнь, полюбил он ее, и трудно было расстаться с ней. И тогда Великий червь стал плакать, и слезы его заполнили мир. Так появилась вода.*

Answer (score 2):

```
  В данном случае приставка при- пишется по правилу, т.к. 
  слово с этой приставкой обозначает "неполноту действия". Не 
  горюет, а только пригорюнился. Или, для примера: "сесть" и 
  "присесть", "лечь" и "прилечь".
                                            Из ответов
```

**РЕШЕНИЕ**

1. Итак, пользователи уверены,  что это неполное действие (см. **[ответы](http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/4342189-prigorjunitsja-ili-pregorjunitsja-kak-pravilno.html#answer12320407)**). Но лучше уточнить ситуацию п**о словарю**:

**ГОРЮН**, -а; м. Трад.-нар. =Горемыка. Горюнья, -и; мн. род. -ний; ж. **ГОРЮНИТЬСЯ**, -нюсь, -нишься; нсв. Трад.-нар. Горевать, печалиться. Полно тебе г.! Не горюнься, все образуется. **ПРИГОРЮНИТЬСЯ**, -нюсь, -нишься; св. Разг. Загрустить, приуныть, опечалиться. Что ты пригорюнился? Сидеть пригорюнившись. Пригорюниваться, -аюсь, -аешься; нсв.

2. Из словаря мы видим, как образуется слово: ***горюниться — пригорюниться,*** приставка ***ПРИ*** имеет значение **завершенности** и используется для образования глагола **совершенного** вида.

[Большой толковый словарь](https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8&mode=slovari&l=1&dicts%5B%5D=42)  ***ПРИ***.., **приставка**. 10. Указывает на завершённость действия, доведение состояния до какого-л. результата. Примяться (о растениях), присниться, пригрезиться, примерить (что-л.), приласкать (кого-л.), приготовить (ужин).

3. А вот значение **приближения** для приставки ***ПРИ*** можно увидеть скорее в толковании глагола: ***пригорюниться*** — это вести себя как ***горюн***, который постоянно горюет. Поэтому здесь речь идет скорее о коротком **времени.**

**О ТЕКСТАХ**

1. В современном языке глагол ***пригорюниться*** имеет стилевую пометку **(разг.)**, а общеупотребительным является глагол *опечалиться*:  **ОПЕЧАЛИТЬСЯ**, -люсь, -лишься; св. Прийти в печальное, грустное настроение, стать печальным; огорчиться, расстроиться. Напрасно опечалился, всё будет хорошо!

Глагол ***запечалиться*** также разговорный: **ЗАПЕЧАЛИТЬСЯ,** -люсь, -лишься; св. Разг. Стать печальным; опечалиться.

2. Оба глагола ушли в **разговорную и народно-поэтическую** речь. Интересно, что Иван-царевич **сначала** запечалился по поводу утраты коня, а когда **уже** устал до смерточки, то и пригорюнился.

В "Манюне"  (дядя Миша **пригорюнился**) глагол используется в **ироническом** смысле. У Водолазкина ***опечалиться***также имеет **особую** коннотацию: своему прямому значению глагол явно не соответствует.

Так писатели в своем творчестве используют стилевую характеристику слов для создания нужного **художественного** образа. И тогда разговорные глаголы ***пригорюниться*** и ***запечалиться*** бывают очень кстати.

Comment: _«ЗАПЕЧАЛИТЬСЯ <…> В данном случае нас интересует РЕЗУЛЬТАТИВНОСТЬ действия (стать печальным).»_ === Результативность была бы у приставки ЗА в этом глаголе, если бы ПЕРЕД тем, как ЗАпечалиться, некто печалился, печалился… **И в результате запечалился!** 

Comment: Предлагаю обсудить приставку ЗА в отдельной теме. Задайте вопрос, и наши участники  тоже выскажут свое мнение. Я убрала свой текст про значение приставки из этой темы.

Answer (score 2):

***ПРИГОРЮНИТЬСЯ = ЗАГРУСТИТЬ***

(См. словарь, приведённый в параллельном ответе в этой теме.)

В обоих этих словах приставки имеют значение ***НЕ завершённости***, а наоборот — ***НАЧАЛА*** действий, названных мотивирующими эти слова глаголами (*горюниться, грустить*).

Comment: Спасибо за ваше мнение и интерес к теме (голос от меня). Я выбирала по словарю значение приставки ЗА и думаю,что здесь все-таки значение завершенности действия, а не начала его.  Загрустить, запечалиться, пригорюниться — все это стать грустным-печальным, а не становиться таким.  Сравнить: заиграть, забегать — это начать играть и бегать.

Comment: @Sharon: _«Я выбирала по словарю значение приставки ЗА и думаю,что здесь все-таки значение завершенности действия, а не начала его…. Сравнить: заиграть, забегать — это начать играть и бегать»_.  === Ну так такое же определение словари дают и для слова **загрустить**. См.: 
_ЗАГРУСТИТЬ… **Начать грустить**_.



https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C&mode=all&l=1


https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C&mode=all&l=1

Comment: Спасибо за ваше мнение.